# GetGuiResources WIn32 API usage

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, win32gui

I am trying to use [`GetGuiResources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683192.aspx) to find the Gui resources used by my program.It takes a flag as the second parameter. I am interested to know the difference between `GR_USEROBJECTS` and `GR_GDIOBJECTS` . I couldn't find any documentation around it. Can anyone explain what is the difference between them? I also know that by default maximum 10k GDI handles can be opened process at a time. Is the value returned by `GR_GDIOBJECTS` counted as part of this 10k limit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GR_USEROBJECTS are User32 objects, windows and menus.

GR_GDIOBJECTS are Gdi32 objects, like device contexts, fonts, bitmaps, cursors, icons, brushes, pens, regions, palettes, metafiles, paths.

There is very little point in actually using GetGuiResources() in a program, these values are readily visible in Task Manager.  View + Select Columns and tick USER Objects and GDI Objects.  There ought to be a ton of web pages that talk about these counters.

The default 10,000 handle quota is per-process.  There's a limit on the total number of handles created by all processes in a session, a backgrounder can be seen in article ["Pushing the Limits of Windows: USER and GDI Objects – Part 1"](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-8211-part-1/ba-p/723881).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I am trying to figure out a GDI leak in my application and using the GetGuiResources to monitor the usage.. Had one more related question..Does graphic driver anything to do with the  GDI leaks? i.e. can a faulty driver cause GDI leaks in my application?

Comment: No, the device driver is never at fault.  A GDI leak is a pure programming bug.  Very common, short from forgetting to release the handle with the appropriate release function (there is more than one), a standard bug is to forget to restore the device context before destroying it.  Never ignore the return value of a SelectObject() call, another SelectObject() call is required afterwards to restore the DC.

Comment: Finally figured out the leak. It was caused by not deleting the bitmap handles returned from `GetIconInfo()` call.